# Express route not returning

Tags: node.js, express

Probably a silly mistake but I cannot see why I'm not getting a response from a GET request.

This is part of my server file located in the root:

```
//server.js
...
var serverRoutes = require('./server/routes');
app.use('/server', serverRoutes);
...
```

and my routes file:

```
//server/routes/index.js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

module.exports = function() {
  router.get('/test', function(req, res, next){
    console.log("HIT");
    res.status(200).send("OK");
  });

  return router;
}
```

Everytime I navigate to `/server/test` in my browser it just stalls. Nothing is logged in the terminal and no "OK" response is received in the browser - what am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `serverRoutes` module exports a function that returns a router. You need to invoke it in order to pass the `Router` instance it returns to `app.use`:

```
app.use('/server', serverRoutes());
```

Otherwise, express is going to treat your exported function as a middleware, which will cause the app to hang since it does nothing with the `response` passed to it.

Comment: Great - that would have taken me all year to find!